# Why is my filter glitchy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have build a filter on: http://www.helvar.nl/nieuws

but it is very glitchy, I tried everything that may help like

.stop() and
delete all css transitions

but nothing helps..

Can somebody maybe help with whats going on?

I bit of my javascript:

```
    var oldCategory = false;
    var wrapper = "#news-container";

    function filter(categoryId){
        $('.filter-list li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        currentHeight = $(wrapper).height(); 
        console.log('currentHeight ', currentHeight);

        $('.mix2').hide();
        $('.category-'+categoryId).show();

        contentHeight = $(wrapper).height();
        console.log('contentHeight ', contentHeight);

        $(wrapper).height(currentHeight);
        $(wrapper).delay(100).animate(
            {
                height: contentHeight
            },
            200, 
            function(){
                $(wrapper).height('auto');
            }
        );

        $('.mix2').hide();
        if(oldCategory){
            $('.category-'+oldCategory).show();
            $('.category-'+oldCategory).stop().fadeOut(function(){
                $('.category-'+categoryId).show();
            });
        } else {
            $('.mix2').show();
            $('.mix2').stop().fadeOut(function(){
                $('.category-'+categoryId).show();
            });
        }
        oldCategory = categoryId;
    }
    function showAllFiltered(){
        $('.mix2').fadeIn('200');
    };
    $(function() {
        $('.filter-list li, .filter-list-mobile li').click(function(){
            $('.filter-list li, .filter-list-mobile li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

Comment: 1. jQuery < 3 doesn't have great animation performance. 2. Animating layout-related properties like `height` doesn't have great performance either.

Comment: okay, I did not know that, is there another way to animate that?

Comment: To avoid jQuery you can use CSS animations or a JavaScript library such as the Web Animations API polyfill, GSAP, or Velocity.js. Getting around animating `height` is trickier and there's no real solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what the problem is.

it is in this piece of code:

```
$(wrapper).delay(100).animate(
   {
       height: contentHeight
    },
    200, 
    function(){
       $(wrapper).height('auto');
    }
);
```

The animation is first going on the contentHeight and the after that animation the height is set to 'auto' so it flickers when I do it.

I have to find another way to animate the height.

Comment: You should use CSS3 transitions, it's a lot easier, semantically it's cleaner, and there are also arguments for it's performance (I'm not going to go into that). Simply set a class with your javascript and define the transitions and style attributes in CSS - the browser will natively take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I set the height to auto after the height is set to contentHeight?

Comment: Same as you'd set any other height in CSS, `height: auto;`